# Modify variable just in the Django admin but not in database

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to modify a single value when I open an instance of a model in the Django admin.
Basically I want to display a value that is the opposite of the one stored in the database. So here is what I did in admin.py :

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    import_file = forms.FileField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.instance.value)
        self.instance.value = self.instance.get_reverted_value()
        print(self.instance.value)
```

I works I can see it with the prints, but the admin still displays the original value that is stored in database.
Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it read-only or will you have to revert back when saving the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModelAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['value'].value = self.instance.get_reverted_value()
```

Comment: Can't do the second option because self.instance isn't initialized before the call to super. (don't ask me why I wouldn't know)

Comment: I edited the answer, this should work. Provided, I remembered the '.value' part correctly. It may be '.initial' or something like that.

Comment: It works, the value is modified but I guess Django doesn't like it because the value displayed is still the one in the database. Weird. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The self.fields['value'].value is correct. Are you sure there isn't a problem somewhere else?

Comment: So the form in the browser is still displaying the value that's in the DB, not the one that self.instance.get_reverted_value() returns?

Comment: Yes but I think I found a solution :) Thanks